# Getting Error when query mongodb with AND and OR Condition in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

In my project i need to query from mongodb with the query having AND and OR, but i am getting error.

below is my code:

```
*** Variables ***
${host}    mongodb://username:password@192.10.23.126/RegressionDB
${port}    27017
${mongDBName}   RegressionDB
${mongoCollection}  Service

${mQuery}        { "service.offerings.offering.offeringType.masterCode": "Plan", $or: [ { "service.offerings.offering.offeringSubType.masterCode": "WS" }, { $and: [ { "service.isDeliveryRequired": "N" } ] } ] }

${mReturnFields}    service.customerCode
${isReturnID}     False

*** Test Cases ***
Query from MongoDatabase
    Connect To MongoDB    ${host}    ${port}
    ${result}=  Retrieve Mongodb Records With Desired Fields  ${mongDBName}  ${mongoCollection}   ${mQuery}   ${mReturnFields}   ${isReturnID}
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 58 (char 57)
```

The same query i executed using `MongoChef` it worked fine, but not working with robot framework, what can be the reason.

Comment: The first step is to log `${mQuery}` to make sure it looks the way you think it should.

Comment: The query worked fine, if the query doesn't have AND or OR

Comment: { "service.offerings.offering.offeringType.masterCode": "Plan", $or: [ { "service.offerings.offering.offeringSubType.masterCode": "WS" }, { $and: [ { "service.isDeliveryRequired": "N" } ] } ] }          Is this your query?? would you need $or / $and ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not related to AND and OR, I guess it has to do with setting properties! when you are setting properties, the values have to be in double quotes. Since it works for normal query and only throws this error for and/or so can you try add and/or in double quotes!

That should fix it!

Comment: hi waman, i didn't understand setting properties means, in my mongoquery, all the key value pairs are with double quotes, where it missed i am not able to find. Can you help me on this

Comment: yeah name value pairs are enclosed in double quotes. as you told it works for normal query and only throws this error for and/or so can you try add and/or in double quotes!

Comment: Though I have not worked on mongoDb, I just guess this because mongoDo python lib might use JSON to store these properties somewhere in the code and that's where you see this error! Just a thought though!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have included `$or` and `$and` also in double quotes then it worked, can you update the answer i will accept it